# Line containing bounty is too small

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, stackexchange-2.0, rendering

When the bounty line appears, on my system the line is not high enough to fully display the arrow:

[Erroneous rendering http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/9374/bountyarrow.png](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/9374/bountyarrow.png)

(and of course I'm using the default text size).

I'm using Firefox 3.6.8 on Linux, but it looks the same in current versions of Chrome and Opera here.

**EDIT:** [The original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40/how-do-i-label-different-rows-or-columns-of-a-matrix-using-braces) that has a bounty. Note that the bounty ends tomorrow.

[Another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4245/how-to-beat-the-time-challenge-in-the-first-level-of-dale-and-peakot) has a bounty that lasts 7 days at the moment.

Comment: Could you link to that question please?

Comment: @jjn Probably not the same question, but I spied the same effect on the Gaming site on http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3573/the-name-of-an-ibm-pc-puzzle-game-from-the-80s-something-to-do-with-a-penguin-o, but not with http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/help-me-with-the-name-of-a-dos-game. It seems to occur because the display name of the user is too short. IE8 on XP, here (Chrome's at home!)

Comment: @Grace, it is definitely because the first link is only one line, and the second is 2.

Comment: @jjnguy: that's indeed the case. For me, both bounty lines in the questions provided by Grace are on one line; [this one](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/409/free-alternatives-to-google-wave) isn't, and looks all right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we have bounty reasons, the box is always going to be tall enough to show the arrow